# How do I specify a particular endpoint with a topic/subscription in Azure ServiceBusTriggerAttribute?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-4.5, servicebus

I have created a service bus topic (*my-topic*) in my Azure account.   I have created a listen only rule (*listen_rule*) on that topic, and also a subscription to that topic (*my-subscription*), for my code to trigger on.

How do I add that specific subscription/rule to the `[ServiceBusTrigger]` ?

In app.config I have this configuration section:

```
<add key="MySubscription" value="my-subscription" />
<add key="MyTopic" value="Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listen_rule;SharedAccessKey=XXXX=;EntityPath=my-topic"/>
```

In my code I have:

```
    public async Task ProcessMyMessageAsync(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("%MyTopic%", "%MySubscription%")]
        BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage)
```

This throws an exception:

> The entity path/name 'Endpoint=sb://XXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listen_rule;SharedAccessKey=XXXX=;EntityPath=topic'  exceeds the '50' character limit.

I've found lots of examples on the web where there is a generic `AzureWebJobsServiceBus` connection string, but that gives access to the whole service bus, I want to lock it down to this particular topic/rule.

*p.s.
I'm using .NET framework 4.5.2 (yeah, I know, it's an old application), and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 2.0.0.*

*p.p.s.  Ideally, I'd like to specify the whole subscription in one configuration line if possible.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this myself, incase anyone else found this issue:

I was missing a connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AzureWebJobsMyEndPoint" connectionString="Endpoint=sb://XXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listen_rule;SharedAccessKey=XXXX"/>
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  <add key="MySubscription" value="subscription-name"/>
  <add key="MyTopic" value="topic-name"/>
</appSetting>
```

And I needed `ServiceBusAccountAttribute` on the trigger:

```
public async Task ProcessMyMessageAsync(
    [ServiceBusAccount("MyEndPoint")]
    [ServiceBusTrigger("%MyTopic%", "%MySubscription%", AccessRights.Listen)]
    BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage)
```

Notice how the `ServiceBusAccount` used *MyEndPoint*, but the connection string uses that as a suffix to *AzureWebJobs*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it takes your topic name , subscription name and servicebus connection string as parameters,

`public async Task ProcessMyMessageAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("%MyTopic%","%MySubscription%", Connection = "ServiceBusEndPoint")]BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage)`

and in your appsettings

`<add key="MySubscription" value="my-subscription" />
<add key="MyTopic" value="my-topic"/>
<Add Key="ServiceBusEndPoint" value="Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listen_rule;SharedAccessKey=XXXX="/>`

If this doesnt work try adding the servicebusendpoint in connection string instead of app setting that should work.

update for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 2.0.0.

use can setup the service bus connection string and storage connection string over here in program.cs

`

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration("your storage connection string ");

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();

        }
        config.UseServiceBus(new ServiceBusConfiguration() { ConnectionString = "your servcebus connection string " });
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
`
```

// Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
        // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage

Comment: `Connection` is not available in the version of the nuget package I'm using.

Comment: @Neil,What do you mean `Connection is not available in the version of the nuget package I'm using.`?  Specify your function package version, the connection is the TriggerAttribute.

Comment: In the question (near the bottom), I say it's version 2.0.0 of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.  This version doesn't have the 'Connection' parameter.

Comment: @Neil,you are using service bus trigger, it's azure function. For more infortaion, refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration

Comment: @Neil please check the updated answer .. please feel free to comment if you have any further queries

Comment: I need to have the configuration on each function, rather than one service bus for the whole application.  Each topic will have a different SharedAccessKeyName.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get service bus trigger, one is webjob and one is azure function. I check the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 2.0.0` package looks like this trigger doesn't support the connection property.

Mostly I suppose you want to use the webjob sdk. So below is my environment.

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.0.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core 2.0.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 2.0.0

In the app.config, I set the `AzureWebJobsServiceBus` connection.

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsServiceBus" connectionString="service bus connection string"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then below is my **Program.cs**.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

namespace WebJob1
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.UseServiceBus();

            if (config.IsDevelopment)
            {
                config.UseDevelopmentSettings();

            }

            var host = new JobHost(config);
            // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

And the below is my **Function.cs**. I set the connection with the `ServiceBusAccount` attribute. I found it here:[Attributes and annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations).

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace WebJob1
{
    public class Functions
    {

        [ServiceBusAccount("AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger(topicName:"testtopic",subscriptionName:"testsub", access: AccessRights.Manage)] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my test screenshot.

[image]

And if you want is azure function you could refer to the official tutorial:[Create your first function using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio#create-a-function-app-project) and this [service bus binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus)(other pages have the trigger information)

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I need to have the configuration on each function, rather than one service bus for the whole application. Each topic will have a different SharedAccessKeyName.

Comment: So just in each function use the `ServiceBusAccount`  with different key name. you don't have to use AzureWebJobsServiceBus as the key  name.

Comment: @Neil, any update on this issue? If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: Your answer did help, but it isn't actually the answer.  `[ServiceBusAccount]` was the key, but I had to suffix a connection string like: "AzureWebJobsXXXXX"

Comment: `ServiceBusAccount` is not a key, it's a property, check my code, `AzureWebJobsServiceBus` is the key.

Comment: @Neil, you could check this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations

Comment: I meant, the key, as in the information I needed to solve the problem :-) AzureWebJobsServiceBus is used if you don't specify `ServiceBusAccount`.

Comment: Actually I can't figure out what's your meaning 'AzureWebJobsServiceBus is used if you don't specify ServiceBusAccount'. Suppose you don't check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations), there is a description about Service Bus account order. If you don't set any attribute  or connection, it will use `AzureWebJobsServiceBus`  app setting.

Comment: I did read the docs, but it's not very clear.  If you read the bullet points at the bottom of the `ServiceBusAccountAttribute` section, you see how the `AzureWebJobServiceBus` app setting is the default if no other account is specified.  It doesn't mention how if you specify a `ServiceBusAccount`, how that key is specified in appsettings (there is some other documentation that does mention it).